# how to write a webservice client ?i have just .xsd file with me and the url of the server.How to start with?

Tags: web-services

how to write a webservice client ?i have just .xsd file with me and the url of the server.How to start with?

I dont have wsdl with me.

Comment: where should i give accept rating in the web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day a web service is little different to a web page - you send a request to it and you get a response back. WSDL and SOAP are "just" wrappers and helpers that aim to make things easier in various respects.

So... its unlikely - though not impossible - that the *only* information you have is a .xsd, and its the other documentation that you need to start with.